# save content into an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I generate an array with a php file by calling a remote server. The return looks as follows.
How can I capture this content into an array?

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
[ID] => 00d9fd1b-5533-423a-9396-06ccbd69a06f
[NAME] => Icecream
[PRICE] => 3 
    )
[1] => Array (
[ID] => 022a8ef9-435c-4cb3-9977-87abba6649e4
[NAME] => Chocolate
[PRICE] => 12
    )
)
```

My php file calls the other php file and makes an sql query with using POST method. I try to capture the content as follows, but doesn't work. The whole array will be in another array...

```
$result = do_post_request("http://www.example.com/proxyslq.php", "query=SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS", 0);
```

Sorry if the question is wrong, I'm a beginner programmer.

Comment: What is `do_post_request`, where did you define that?

Comment: Thats for getting data from the other php file with POST method.

Comment: Could you clarify "The whole array will be in another array..." please?

Comment: @Joey I get that, but where did you define it? How does it work?

Comment: So, you are trying to have one PHP file access an array from another PHP file?  Is that right?  I suggest having the return do `echo json_encode($data)`, then on the other side you can do `json_decode($result, TRUE);` to get it back.

Comment: Yes, the goal is, that php file on the remote server gives me an aswer based on an sql query. I want to load the answer into an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize array in remote server and unserialize the string to get array:

```
$string = serialize($array);

$array = unserialize($string);
```